# Passing prompt values into functions triggered by "click" event on input buttons

Tags: javascript, button, input, onclick, click

I have a code which is intended to create 3 buttons (with JavaScript) and **on each one of them I'm adding an event listener** for *click event*. All of the buttons will execute the same function when it's clicked which is the *mathProb()* **[I know it doesn't make much sense but I just want to experiment with things]**.

*mathProb()* function needs 3 arguments:

1. *firstNumber* which is the first operand.
2. *secondNumber* which is the second operand
3. *operationSign* which is the operation to be performed between the two operands

Here's the ***mathProb*** function (I put the function in the HTML head element):

```
function mathProb(firstNumber, secondNumber, operationSign){
        switch(operationSign){
            case "+":
                var sum = (firstNumber + secondNumber).toFixed(2);
                document.writeln("The sum of [" + firstNumber + " + " + secondNumber + "] is " + sum + " (adjusted to 2 decimal places)");
                break;

            case "-":
                var subtract = (firstNumber - secondNumber).toFixed(2);
                document.writeln("The subtraction of [" + firstNumber + " - " + secondNumber + "] is " + subtract + " (adjusted to 2 decimal places)");
                break;

            case "*":
                var multiplication = (firstNumber * secondNumber).toFixed(2);
                document.writeln("The multiplication of [" + firstNumber + " X " + secondNumber + "] is " + multiplication + " (adjusted to 2 decimal places)");
                break;

            case "/":
                var division = (firstNumber / secondNumber).toFixed(2);
                document.writeln("[" + firstNumber + " divided by " + secondNumber + "] is " + division + " (adjusted to 2 decimal places)");
                break;

            default:
                document.writeln("You did not specify the operation sign, no operation could be performed between the two numbers!");
        }
    }
```

Now I'm planning to use the *prompt()* method to get the 3 arguments which will be used by the function, therefore the JavaScript code I put in the body element looks like this:

```
    //create all the mathematical buttons
    var addButton = document.createElement("input");
    var subtractButton = document.createElement("input");
    var multiplyButton = document.createElement("input");
    var divideButton = document.createElement("input");
    addButton.type = "button";
    subtractButton.type = "button";
    multiplyButton.type = "button";
    divideButton.type = "button";

    var firstNumber = parseFloat(prompt("Please enter the first number"));
    var secondNumber = parseFloat(prompt("Please enter the second number"));
    var operationSign = prompt("Please enter the operation sign you wish to perform on the two numbers");


    //add a click event listener to all of the buttons
    addButton.addEventListener("click", mathProb(firstNumber,secondNumber,operationSign));
    subtractButton.addEventListener("click", mathProb(firstNumber,secondNumber,operationSign));
    multiplyButton.addEventListener("click", mathProb(firstNumber,secondNumber,operationSign));
    divideButton.addEventListener("click", mathProb(firstNumber,secondNumber,operationSign));

    //add all the buttons to the body of the document
    document.body.appendChild(addButton);
    document.body.appendChild(subtractButton);
    document.body.appendChild(multiplyButton);
    document.body.appendChild(divideButton);
```

*I realised that I haven't added any "value" to the buttons so I won't be able to differentiate them right now*

My problem is that, once I run my code, I got the 3 prompts which will ask me for the *firstNumber*, the *secondNumber*, and the *operationSign*. However, for some reason, it seems like ***mathProb()*** function was executed 4 times **Without ME CLICKING ON ANY OF THE BUTTONS**

Here's what happened when I put ***2*** as the firstNumber, ***3*** as the secondNumber and ***+*** as operationSign:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tIxd.jpg

See what I'm saying? I have no idea what happened here and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with the code either (I'm very inexperienced when it comes to javascript/html/css).

Comment: this is a side note: wouldn't it make sense to have "equals" button that calls mathProb() on click instead of four operation buttons, since you are prompting user for operation already?

Comment: @classicalConditioning 

ahhh, you mean, something like 
<input type="button" onclick="mathProb(firstNumber, secondNumber, operationSign)">

Yeah I haven't tried that because I'm trying to dive deep into javascript right now, but yeah I'll definitely try that as well in the future haha.

Comment: no, what i meant was: why do you add four buttons, with four different listeners that call the same function passing the operation variable that you prompted for up front? It does not matter what button is clicked - the result will be the same

Comment: @classicalConditioning

Ah, I know it doesn't make sense at all. I can literally just put one button just like what Sagar V said (you can see his answer below). I was just trying to experiment with things really, just trying to see what will happen if I have 4 different buttons that will call the same function when clicked. 

Cheers mate, thanks a lot for the reply ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
.addEventListener("click", mathProb(firstNumber,secondNumber,operationSign));
```

Should look like:

```
.addEventListener("click", function(evt) { 
mathProb(firstNumber,secondNumber,operationSign);
});
```

If You want to deliver function to argument (without execution) use functionName without ().

Example:

```
var someFunctionWithFunctionInArgument = function(fun) {
  fun(1);
};

var superFunction = function(num) {
 alert(num);
};

someFunctionWithFunctionInArgument(superFunction); // alert 1

someFunctionWithFunctionInArgument(superFunction(2)); // alert 2 and error becouse fun is not a function now
```

Comment: A more verbose explanation will help OP understand better :)

Comment: Ahhh I see how it is, so basically just pass the function reference otherwise the function will be executed right away. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You are going too complex.
You can have this simple solution

```js
function operate(val1,op,val2){
  switch(op){
    case '+' : return val1+val2; break;
    case '-' : return val1-val2; break;
    case '*' : return val1*val2; break;
    case '/' : return val1/val2; break;
    default : return 0; break;
  }
}
var start = document.createElement('button');
start.innerHTML="START";
start.addEventListener('click',function(){
  var result=operate(parseInt(prompt("first val")),prompt("Operator"),parseInt(prompt("Second val")));
  console.log(result);
});
document.body.appendChild(start);
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Or even more simple

```js
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerHTML="START";
button.addEventListener('click',function(){
  var val1=parseInt(prompt("First Val"));
  var op=prompt("Operator");
  var val2=parseInt(prompt("Second Val"));
  console.log(eval(val1+op+val2));
});
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Even more simple

```js
function start(){
  console.log(eval(prompt("Enter expression : "))); // like 10+5
}
function startWithTest(){
  var exp=prompt("Enter expression : ");
  if(/^\d+[+-\/*]{1}\d+$/.test(exp)){
    console.log(eval(exp));
  }
}
```

```html
<body><button onclick="start();">START</button>&ensp;With validating :&ensp;<button onclick="startWithTest();">START With Test</button></body>
```

Comment: Whoa, haven't thought about that, again like I said I"m very noob at this, I'm really trying to learn haha. Thanks a lot mate!